# manager / employee database design

Tags: database, database-design

How would you modify the manager/employee relationship (as seen [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php)) if managers have an additional attribute that normal employees lack?

For example, if managers are assigned a parking spot (which itself would be a reference to a parking spot table).

Comment: What is your starting point in terms of what tables do you have now and how are they related to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the solution would be a "assigned_to" column in the parking lot table. Your database doesn't need to know who has the right to "own" a parking lot in my opinion.

As altenrnative: create a table with parking lot and employee as columns, if more than one employee(or manager) can share a parking_lot.

One sidenote: it looks as if you are designing your database for the actual situation - that might change in the future; you cannot know if normal employees won't get a parking lot in the future!

Comment: I used parking spots as an example.